# Consulta MySQL relación de tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, tablas

Tengo dos tablas:
Tabla 1) CUIT
Tabla 2) Proveedores

En la Tabla 1) tengo solo el campo CUIT con varios registros, todos con un Cuit Distinto.

En la tabla 2) tengo la Razon Social, comprobantes, tipo de comprobantes, etc.

En la tabla 2) la Razon Social se repite en varios registros cada una, porque por ejemplo una razon socual puede tener varios comprobantes entonces tengo varios registros con la misma razon social.

La tabla 1) solo tiene el CUIT de cada Razon social y lo que necesito es hacer una consulta que me devuelva todos los registros de la tabla proveedores de una razon social en particular, de acuerdo al cuit.

Como puedo encararlo? alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], considera editar pues seria genial para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta el agregar lo que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: Faltan datos para responder tu pregunta. La tabla 2 tiene el campo cuit? Te ayudaría bastante decir los campos en cada tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Como no muestras más información (campos de cada tabla) te mostraré una manera muy rápida de hacerlo:

```
SELECT * FROM CUIT C INNER JOIN Proveedores P ON P.cuit_id = P.id_cuit WHERE C.id_cuit = <valor>
```

En caso de que tengas duda de que hace referencia a que te dejo esto:

```
SELECT <campos> FROM <tabla1> <aliastabla1> INNER JOIN <tabla2> <aliastabla2> ON <aliastabla2>.<llave_secundaria_tabla_1> = <aliastabla1>.<llave_primaria_tabla_1> WHERE <aliastabla1>.<llave_primaria_tabla_1> = <tuvalor>
```

Intentalo, espero que te funcione.